# Error exporting data.frame as csv

Tags: r

Exporting data.frame as .csv with code.

```
write.csv(df, "name.csv")
```

LogitTV.Rda has 3000 rows and 4 columns.

My code has an error when identifying the data.frame.

```
load("~/Home Automation/LogitTV.Rda")
write.csv(LogitTV.Rda, "LogitTV.csv")
```

> Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'LogitTV.Rda' not found

Checked the following:

1) Cleaned the console of previous history

2) Working Directory set as ~/Home Automation/

Anything else to check for preventing the error?

Thanks

Comment: "LogitTV.Rda" might be the name of the file, but that has nothing to do with what is the name of the object that was loaded from it.

Answer (score 3):

`LogitTV.Rda` is, confusingly, **not** the name of the object that gets loaded.

Try:

```
loadedObj <- load("~/Home Automation/LogitTV.Rda")
write.csv(get(loadedObj), file="LogitTV.csv")
```

This assumes that the `.Rda` file contains only a single R object, and that it is a data frame or matrix.

It would be nice if `write.csv` had a way to accept the name of an object instead of the object itself (so `get()` was unnecessary), but I don't know of one.

Comment: To check object names in the `.Rda` file compare `ls()` before and after, I assume? `LS <- ls() ; #Do stuff; ls()[!ls() %in% LS]`

Comment: you could, but why not just print the value of `loadedObj` ... ?

Comment: That approach makes more sense, I just find it frustrating that `load` creates an object in your workspace in the same way `<<-` would inside a function. Personally I think `load` should return the object itself.

Comment: @BenBolker the command created a .csv file, but added a column numbering rows. For example, excel column "A" row 1 displays nothing, row 2 displays 1, row 3 displays 2, ect. Deleting column "A" and moving the other 4 rows over fixed the problem.

Comment: @SeñorO, I agree. I think `load` might have been written back in the days when we still thought `attach()` was a good idea too.

Comment: @ScottDavis, did you try `row.names=FALSE` in the `write.csv()` call?

Comment: @BenBolker writing loadedObj <- load("~/Home Automation/LogitTV.Rda") then write.csv(get(loadedObj), file="LogitTV.csv", row.names = FALSE) worked. Thanks again for you help.